# Printing values from an XML file

Tags: php, xml

XML file (ids is not the root):

```
<id_list>
    <ids>
        <id>185903535</id>
        <id>235450977</id>
        <id>274135256</id>
    </ids>
</id_list>
```

I am trying to print all the values in the XML file.  I am very new to PHP and all I can print is the first element.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('txt.xml');//php5
echo $xml->ids->id;
?>
```

I am sure it is something very simple and I've tried searching google but I am not exactly sure how to word what I am looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access all of the `<id>` nodes, simply iterate over the `$xml->ids->id` object:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('txt.xml');
foreach ($xml->ids->id as $id) {
    echo $id;
}
```

[Relevant documentation](http://php.net/manual/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5152)

Comment: Thank you so much this works!  Is there a way to print the values on a newline?

Comment: @bardockyo:  If you're using this script to generate an HTML page, try `echo`ing `<br />` will insert a line break. If you're using it in the command line, `echo`ing a `"\n"` character will print a new line.